# Not able to create new Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am new to Firebird. I installed Firebird Superserver 2.5 with "Install as application" option. I also installed FlameRobin GUI front-end. When I am trying to create a new database with `SYSDBA` username and `masterkey` as password, it displays following error:

[image]

I am installing on Windows 7 and want to use it on a single PC.

Comment: Belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, is the server running? If you installet it as a application and server is running then there should be FireBird icon in the system tray. If there isn't then start the server, ie execute command line

> fbserver.exe -a